# C++ Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I am trying to call a class member from within the class.

```
class gaugeClass{
  public:
    static const byte devAddr;
    struct Flasht{
      struct Thresholdt{
        byte addr = 0x81;
        boolean val = 0;
        void get_threshold(){
          readReg( this );
        }
      } threshold;
    } ;
    template<typename T>
    static void readReg( T& dataParam ){
      dataParam->val = readDataReg( devAddr, dataParam->addr );
    }
  private:
    static boolean readDataReg( byte devAddr, byte regAddr );
};
const byte gaugeClass::devAddr = 0xD6;
```

The line `readReg( this );` is giving me a non-const error.

I want to be able to alter the value of the member, so I don't want it to be constant. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `template<typename T>
    static void readReg( T* dataParam )`? (`*` instead of `&`)

Comment: or pass `*this` and change `->` by `.`.

Comment: You need to show us the "referenced from" line where readReg is called.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks that did the trick. It also compiles as`T` without either `&` or `*`.

Comment: @GemTaylor `readReg` is called from within the `void get_threshold` function. Thanks